# how to decrease modal header default height in bootstrap 4

Tags: css, modal-dialog, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I want to decrease bootstrap 4 modal default height and width . For this purpose , I have written the following code :

```
<div class="modal-header" style="background-color: darkblue;color:#fff;height:5%;!important">
  <p class="mx-auto d-block">Please Give Your Finger</p>  
</div>
```

I have set the height of modal header to 5% . But the height is same as default . How can I decrease the bootstrap modal header height ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Bootstrap 4's default `modal-header` does not have a height, it's padded out to be content appropriate (you can see this from the Developer Tools in your browser):

```
.modal-header {
    // ..
    padding: 1rem;
}
```

Simply adjust the padding as necessary on the element, rather than trying to set `height`.

As an aside, I'd suggest using a header (since that's what it is) for your title text, rather than a paragraph.

```
<div class="modal-header pt-reduced pb-reduced">
     <h5 class="modal-title">Please give your finger</h5>
</div>
```

(where `.pt-reduced` and `.pb-reduced` are classes appropriate for reducing the padding on the top and bottom respectively)

Comment: Where `reduced` would be an integer lower than 3, e.g. `<div class="modal-header pt-2 pb-2">`. See [Bootstrap Spacing](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/spacing/).